# Rails 5.2 Polymorphic Association with polymorphic conditional

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, polymorphism, ruby-on-rails-5.2

#### MODELS:

```
class Car < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user

  has_one  :listing, as: :listable
  has_one  :firm, as: :firmable
  has_one  :seller, as: :sellable
end

class Truck < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user

  has_one  :listing, as: :listable
  has_one  :firm, as: :firmable
  has_one  :seller, as: :sellable
end

class Listing < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :listable, polymorphic: true
  has_many :favorites, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :users_who_favorited, through: :favorites, source: :user
end
```

And Assume that Car and Truck both have a user_id field....

`Listing.includes(:listable)` returns an eargerloaded listings AR relation.

However, I need to filter by the user_id, so I tried...

`Listing.includes(:listable).where(user_id: 100)`

but I get an error..

> ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR:  column listings.user_id does not exist)
>       LINE 1: SELECT  "listings".* FROM "listings" WHERE "listings"."user_...

As it seems to be looking up user_id on listings. However, I need to filter on listables table, so that would mean either the Car or Truck tables. However listable is defined.

I also tried:

`Listing.includes(listable:[:user]).where('users.id = 100')`

but I get...

> ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table "users")
>       LINE 1: SELECT  "listings".* FROM "listings" WHERE (users.id = 100) ...
>                                                           ^
>       : SELECT  "listings".* FROM "listings" WHERE (users.id = 100) LIMIT $1

#### UPDATE:

Then tried

```
class Listing < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :listable, polymorphic: true
  has_many :favorites, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :users_who_favorited, through: :favorites, source: :user

  belongs_to :car, -> { includes(:listable).where(listable: { listable_type: Car.to_s }) }, foreign_key: :listable_id
  belongs_to :truck, -> { includes(:listable).where(listable: { listable_type: Truck.to_s }) }, foreign_key: :listable_id

end
```

and tried `Listing.includes(:car, :truck)` but got..

> ActiveRecord::ConfigurationError (Can't join 'Car' to association named 'listable'; perhaps you misspelled it?)

Therefore, I can not try the below until the above is working.

`Listing.includes(:car, :truck).where(cars: { user_id: 1 }).or(Listing.includes(:car, :truck).where(trucks: { user_id: 1 }))`

However, I can do Listing.includes(:listable) and it does work, it breaks when I add a conditional.

Comment: Interesting question. But since includes generates separate select query you will not be able to use the polymorphic table's column in the where clause.
However, you cannot use joins either as you cannot eagerload polymorphic associations.

My suggestion is you could write the SQL query and query using `ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(sql)`
Would love to know if there is any other way.

Comment: You need to create a listable concern for your model.
In your concern
    has_one :listing,
            as: : listable,
            dependent: :destroy

Comment: @Saifchaudhry, Can you expand on your recommendation?

Comment: @Surya, What would the SQL look like? I am having a hard time with it.

Comment: Have you tried Listing.includes(:users).where(users: [id: 10])

Comment: The relation is user->car->listing.  So there is no direct connection of listing to user, I updated my listing model to make that clearer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a very interesting question that I had for several months. Then I found a solution for it.

In your `Listing` model, in order to be able to include your `polymorphic` model, you'll need to tell your model that they are related.

```
class Car < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user

  has_one  :listing, as: :listable
  has_one  :firm, as: :firmable
  has_one  :seller, as: :sellable
end

class Truck < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user

  has_one  :listing, as: :listable
  has_one  :firm, as: :firmable
  has_one  :seller, as: :sellable
end

class Listing < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :listable, polymorphic: true
  has_many :favorites, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :users, through: :favorites

  #magic happens here
  belongs_to :car, -> { includes(:listings).where(listings: { listable_type: Car.to_s }) }, foreign_key: :listable_id
  belongs_to :truck, -> { includes(:listings).where(listings: { listable_type: Truck.to_s }) }, foreign_key: :listable_id

end
```

and now, you can simply do: `Listing.includes(:car, :truck)` and it will work perfectly :-)

For your case:

```
Listing.includes(:car, :truck).where(cars: { user_id: 1 }).or(Listing.includes(:car, :truck).where(trucks: { user_id: 1 }))
```

Comment: Why did you use Listable instead of Listing? I need to return listing objects, not the listable object.

Comment: My bad, it was a typo :)

Comment: Tried your solution, but got.. ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table "listable")
LINE 1: ...ON "cars"."id" = "listings"."listable_id" AND "listable"...

Comment: @user2012677 try it now, it should be `listings` instead of `listable` in the `where` condition

Answer (score 0):

For those that may have as much trouble solving this as me...

#### My Final Solution:

```
    def left_join_listable(table_name, listable_type_value)
      "LEFT OUTER JOIN \"#{table_name}\" "\
      "ON \"#{table_name}\".\"id\" = \"listings\".\"listable_id\" "\
      "AND \"listings\".\"listable_type\" = #{listable_type_value}"
    end

   def left_join_users_on(*table_names)
      join = "LEFT OUTER JOIN \"users\" ON "
      conditionals = table_names.map {|table_name| "\"users\".\"id\" = \"#{table_name}\".\"user_id\"" }.join(" OR ")
      join + conditionals
    end

Listing.joins(left_join_listable('cars',"\'Car\'"))
       .joins(left_join_listable('trucks',"\'Trucks\'"))
       .joins(left_join_users_on('cars','trucks')
       .where(users.id = (?), 100)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm probably missing something here, but why not set up **Car** and **Truck** as STI subclasses under something like **Vehicle**?

And why not turn the **has_one** associations for `firm` and `seller` into **belongs_to** instead, so that each firm or seller can have more than one listing?

```
# Parent class for both Car and Truck
class Vehicle < ApplicationRecord
  # Note that this table has a +type+ column which is used for Single Table Inheritance
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :listings, dependent: :destroy

  # You _might_ want to move these over to Listing so that over time the
  # same vehicle can be listed by different sellers (at different times)
  belongs_to  :firm
  belongs_to  :seller
end

class Car < Vehicle
end

class Truck < Vehicle
end

class Listing < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :vehicle
  has_many :favorites, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :users, through: :favorites
end

class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :vehicles
  has_many :favorites, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :listings, through: :favorites
end

# Associative table between User and Listing
class Favorite < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :listing
end
```

With this kind of setup is there anything you can't query in regards to all of this?