# Rails: Check associated belongs_to object type in a polymorphic relation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, polymorphic-associations

I have three models:

```
class Product
  belongs_to :object, polymorphic: true
  belongs_to :membership, foreign_key: :object_id
  belongs_to :ticket, foreign_key: :object_id
end

class Membership
end

class Ticket
end
```

Say, I have a `product` that has an associated `membership`. E.g. I could do: `product.membership` or `product.object`

But in this case I could also do `product.ticket`.

How can I make sure that Rails raises an error in this case?

Comment: The question does not make sense. What is the polymorphic association even supposted to accomplish if you have foreign key columns pointing to `memberships`  and `tickets` anyways? And by "make sure that Rails raises an error" do you want to raise an exception or add a validation error?

Comment: It is polymorphic @max, the answer is below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably should take a look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21850995/association-for-polymorphic-belongs-to-of-a-particular-type) which reference few solutions for this problem.
Maybe [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57797880/rails-5-2-polymorphic-association-with-polymorphic-conditional) could help you too.

Solutions listed on these posts :

- On Rails 5.2

  ```
  belongs_to :membership, -> { includes(:object).where(products: { object_type: Membership.to_s }) }, foreign_key: :object_id
  belongs_to :ticket, -> { includes(:object).where(products: { object_type: Ticket.to_s }) }, foreign_key: :object_id
  ```
- On Rails 4.2 (but seem deprecated on 6.1 because `foreign_type` is not allowed anymore)

  ```
  belongs_to :membership, -> { where(notes: { object_type: :Membership }) }, foreign_key: :object_id, foreign_type: :Membership, optional: true
  ```
- On Rails 4.1

  ```
  class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  # The true polymorphic association
  belongs_to :object, polymorphic: true

  # The trick to solve this problem
  has_one :self_ref, :class_name => self, :foreign_key => :id

  has_one :membership, :through => :self_ref, :source => :object, :source_type => Membership
  has_one :ticket, :through => :self_ref, :source => :object, :source_type => Ticket
  ```

Comment: Perfect, that makes totally sense. Thank you very much!